# type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter

I am trying to display an image in my Flutter application (test.jpg) that is stored in FireBase. This is my code so far:

```
    StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("/test.jpg");
    String url = (await ref.getDownloadURL()).toString();
    print(url);
    return url;
  }
```

The correct URL prints to console, but if I then try display the url via:

```
Text(_imgUrl)
```

Then I receive the following error:

> type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Could someone please help me understand what the problem is and how to go about correcting it? Please let me know if I should include any other code or information.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please share your function return type, and how it's called.

Comment: add the code of your UI, you may use a FutureBuilder or statefulwidget and setState

Answer (score 0):

Method `getDownloadURL()` returns a `Future<dynamic>`. Change type of your `url` var do `dynamic`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably set `_imgUrl` with `ref.getDownloadURL()` directly without the `await` keyword.

if you set your variable with  `var url = ref.getDownloadURL()` you'll get a `Future<Url>`

but if you set your variable with  `var url = await ref.getDownloadURL()` you'll get a `Url`